# can we change the user syncType from "In cloud" to "Sync with AzureAD" using Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to create a user using Microsoft graph API, and the user we are creating is for a federated domain. The user is getting created, but their syncType is showing as "In Cloud". Because of this, we can't access the user in the directory our domain is sitting, so we cannot access the service like Office 365.

We don't have any on-premises directory and are trying to create a user directly into AAD. Is there any way can we convert this user to "Synced with active directory" via Graph API or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **SMTP Matching** to do it, refer to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2641663/how-to-use-smtp-matching-to-match-on-premises-user-accounts-to-office).

Here is a similar issue, you could refer to [it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b1ef4576-6160-4c0c-ae45-23534d01f55a/convert-quotin-cloudquot-user-to-quotsynced-with-active-directoryquot-users).

> SMTP Matching is an option.
>
> It allows DirSync to link on-premises AD accounts to those created manually in Office 365/AAD.
>
> In addition, during the process of directory synchronization, the data of the on-premises objects will overwrite the data of the corresponding cloud objects whose accounts have SMTP matching configured.
>
> Therefore, we strongly recommend that you back up the existing cloud object data, and then evaluate how you’ve configured SMTP addressing in the cloud.
>
> **Directory synchronization and source of authority**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj863117.aspx